# mobile devices not working with router

Tags: router

I have a router `TL-WR941HP`. When my desktops connect to its wifi then everything works. but when my mobile phone is connected, it behaves in a weird way. like in my mobile, i connect to the wifi and start browsing, but after 1-2 minutes the device cant get any data from the router and shows `no internet`. if i switch off the wifi in my phone and switch on again then it connects to the router and works fine. then after several minutes same problem again.

these are the common settings that i am using:

```
router ip: 10.0.0.1  
default gateway: 10.0.0.1  
ip pool: 10.0.0.100 - 10.0.0.199  
dhcp : enable  
lease time: 120 min  
security: wpa2-psk  
encryption: aes  
mode: 802.11n only (it also supports g/n mixed, b/g/n mixed, i tried changing them)  
channel width: auto (available: auto, 20 mhz, 40 mhz, i tried changing them)  
channel: 3 (available 1-6, also tried with others)
```

my flat's size around 2000 sqft.

because of the `lease time` i have assigned ip to my own devices. e.g. my pc has been given `10.0.0.101` and my phone `10.0.0.102`

before assigning ip manually, my devices were getting ip automatically from the ip pool (because of the dhcp). the previous ip of my phone was `10.0.0.109` but now i have given it `10.0.0.102` manually (hoping that it would solve the problem). now if i go inside my phones settings i can see the ip is `10.0.0.102` but if i go inside the router i can see 2 devices listed there, both have my phone's mac and the have different ips like one is my given `10.0.0.102` and another one is the previous `10.0.0.102`

i rebooted my router from inside and with the switch. switched off/on my phone's wifi. but no luck. where is the problem actually?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on topic here since it concerns a mobile phone and router only. If it's Android then it should be at [android.se].

Comment: Have you switched mobile data off when you are testing this? Are you using a custom ROM? Your lease time is reasonable; I remember I had this kind of a problem on ResurrectionRemix ROM with a particular router from provider. Yours seem to be a decent dedicated router.

Comment: mobile data off, using latest manufacturer ROM.